# $_POST gives index undefined.. how to resolve?

Tags: php, codeigniter, post

I am doing a project in codigniter and I have passed a variable from my controller to view. In view, I am populating a select with the data I passed so when I try to go to next page by using one of the ids from my array (by using $_POST) I always get index undefined. I am new to this and any help is appreciated.
Here is my code:

```
<form method ="post" action ="<?php echo base_url(); ?>test/<?php if(isset($_POST['name'])){$var = $_POST['name'];echo $_POST['name'];}else{$var = null;echo "No name";}?>">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="form-field-select-1">Name</label>
        <select id="name" name="name" class="chosen-select form-control">
          <?php foreach ($names['list_names'] as $p) { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $p['id']; ?>" title="<?php echo $p['fname']; ?>"><?php echo $p['lname'].' '.$p['fname']; ?></option>
          <?php } ?>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type ="submit" class="btn red" style="height: 40px; border-radius:4px;">Continue</button>
  <div class="space-10"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump` or a `print_r` of your `$_POST` superglobal and see if the indexes you're trying to use really exist?

Comment: @JavierLarroulet, yes I already tried to do that and everything seems fine. It gives me undefined index 'name' (this results when I removed isset to do the test and see where the problem is). Usually (with isset), it returns me null.

Comment: Can you update the question with the contents of the `var_dump`?